# utf8 inputenc vs. babel

Tags: babel, unicode, input-encodings, hungarian

I'm using TeXLive 2014 on FreeBSD. Every LaTeX-files produce the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} with
           \usepackage[magyar]{babel}.
```

"Magyar" is the name of the hungarian in hungarian language :)

The relevant part of my documents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\begin{document}
Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép.
\end{document}
```

Can I skip this warning or should do something to fix it? Or maybe it's a bug?

Before TeXLive 2014 this warning didn't appear.

Comment: Altough that's the relevant part of your document, just adding `\begin{document}foo\end{document}` would make it compilable, hence probably saving us a few keystrokes :) I don't know, but may be the warning is because you load `babel` before `inputenc` then `babel` doesn't know that you are going to load `inputenc` later? Also, `utf8x` is usually not recommended, better `utf8`.

Comment: Example improved to save few keystrokes :)
The order of babel and inputenc doesn't matter. With utf8 appears the warning, not only utf8x.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As Psyconaut points out an updated version of `magyar.ldf` is now available on CTAN fixing the problem.

There is some mistake in the tests for input encodings in `magyar.ldf`.  You get the same error message if you choose `latin2` as the encoding.  The relevant part of `magyar.ldf` is:

```
\def\magyar@sugg@ie@lowb#1{\@latex@warning@no@line{Please use \string\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} with\MessageBreak \string\usepackage[#1]{babel}}}%
  %** @param #1 \@inpenc@undefined@
  %** @param #2 input encoding name
  \def\magyar@sugg@ie@low#1#2#3\vfuzz#4{%
    \def\reserved@b{#2}%
    \def\reserved@a{latin2}%
    \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\else
      \def\reserved@a{utf8}%
      \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\else
        \def\reserved@a{utf8x}%
        \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\else
          \def\reserved@a{cp1250}%
          \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\else
            \magyar@sugg@ie@lowb{#4}%
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  }
```

It is clear that what is intended is that `latin2`, `utf8`, `utf8x` or `cp1250` encodings should not give an error.  It looks like this file needs some updating.

Update: more analysis shows that what this command is expecting to receive is

```
 \@inpenc@undefined@ {latin2}....\vfuzz{#1}
```

with `latin2` replaced by whatever encoding has actually been selected, but what it actually receives is

```
 \protect \@inpenc@undefined@ {latin2}....\vfuzz{#1}
```

Thus a simple work around is to change the first line of the definition to

```
 \def\magyar@sugg@ie@low\protect #1#2#3\vfuzz#4{%
```

so the pattern matching gobbles the `\protect`.  At this stage, I suggest you copy `magyar.ldf` to your working directory or local texmf tree and make this change in that copy.

*Update* pts points out that the above does not work in old versions of `babel`.  I can't test that, but his suggestion to change the definition to

```
\def\magyar@sugg@ie@low#1\@inpenc@undefined@#2#3\vfuzz#4{%
```

which apparently works in all versions.  This has now been included in the version of `magyar.ldf` on CTAN, so the recommended action now is to update to that version.

Comment: FYI This workaround works only with the latest version of LaTeX and Babel. It actually breaks older versions.

Comment: A fix, which works with both the old and new Babel, `\def\magyar@sugg@ie@low#1\@inpenc@undefined@#2#3\vfuzz#4{%` has been implemented and available at http://www.math.bme.hu/~pts/cvsget.cgi/u=magyar/p=/M=lakk/c=f1/n=/lakk/texmf/tex/generic/magyar/magyar.ldf

Comment: And the fix mentioned by @pts is now on CTAN, whence it has found (or will find) its way into distributions such as TeX Live.

Comment: @Andrew Swann, could you please fix your answer, incorporating my answer to it? Currently your suggestion for workaround breaks document compilation with old Babel.

Comment: @pts Updated, but I can't test it.  Glad you found a general fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `suggestions=no` option of `magyar.ldf`, and it will be solved your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{defaults=hu-min,suggestions=no}{magyar.ldf}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\begin{document}
Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "problem" does not exist any more with the latest versions of `magyar.ldf`. I fear this answer comes a couple of years too late...

Comment: It works from 2009.