# Why must I use the latin2 encoding for Hungarian?

Tags: babel, input-encodings, hungarian

I'm writing a UTF-8-encoded English document that contains a substantial amount of text in Hungarian (and a few other languages).  When I try to load the Hungarian language patterns in `babel` using `magyar` (or its alias `hungarian`), I get the following compilation warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} with
               \usepackage[magyar]{babel}.
```

I prefer my documents to be encoded in UTF-8, since that's the default encoding on my system, and because it's convenient for me to directly enter symbols like ¶ and — that don't exist in ISO-8859-2.  Why is `babel` insisting that I use the obsolete ISO-8859-2 encoding?  Is something in particular likely to break if I don't use it?  (The `babel` manual is silent on the matter.)  FWIW, I have been ignoring the warning and so far everything seems to work fine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hungarian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
% Following line works fine in spite of the warning
\foreignlanguage{hungarian}{Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The language files are not under control of the babel maintainer. magyar.ldf is a bit outdated. You could write the author (mentioned at the start of magyar.ldf).

Comment: OK, I've written to the author of `magyar.ldf`.  If he doesn't respond here himself, then I will report back what he says.

Comment: On further searching here, this appears to be a bug in `magyar.ldf`.  The solution is documented in [the answer to "utf8 inputenc vs. babel"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205589/utf8-inputenc-vs-babel)