# Please use latin2 or utf8 (inputenc) with magyar babel warning

Tags: babel, hungarian

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\begin{document}
Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép.
\end{document}
```

Compiling this results in a `Please use \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} or \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} with \usepackage[magyar]{babel}` warning.

An [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205589/utf8-inputenc-vs-babel) addressed this, but I still receive this warning, despite the fact that I've the newest `magyar.ldf` in my texmf tree (1.5c) and I've positively verified that it contains the bugfix mentioned there (`\def\magyar@sugg@ie@low#1\@inpenc@undefined@#2#3\vfuzz#4{%`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newest *magyar.ldf* (as of this week) on CTAN doesn't display this warning anymore.

I can confirm that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is a harmless no-op in new versions of latex, pdflatex and lualatex. (I've just tried it with TeX Live 2018 on Linux.)

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` makes a difference in old versions of latex and pdflatex: without it non-ASCII letters don't show up. (This happens in TeX Live 2016 and probably also in TeX Live 2017.)

My recommendation is to keep using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` for compatibility with older versions of latex and pdflatex.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from the 2018-04-01 release, LaTeX directly supports UTF-8, so the instruction `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` does nothing apart from loading `inputenc`. In particular, `utf8.def` is not loaded, which makes `magyar.ldf` that no support for UTF-8 exists.

This should be addressed by the maintainer of `magyar.ldf`.

In the meantime, you can avoid the spurious warning:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with LaTeX 2018-04-01 or later

\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min,suggestions=no}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}

Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép.

\end{document}
```

A different strategy is to keep the same setup as before, but adding a command at the beginning.

```
\UseRawInputEncoding
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}

Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép.

\end{document}
```

The setting to `\magyarOptions` is recommended in the `magyar.ldf` file notes.

Comment: You could also force the definition of `\@inpenc@undefined`, which is where the data comes from

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but since the suggestions are useless anyway, the `suggestions=no` method seems better.

Comment: FYI `suggestions=no` disables other, possibly useful suggestions as well.

Comment: @pts Possibly they can be reinserted with other options.

Comment: @egreg: FYI Right now there are no other options to reinsert the other warnings. My recommendation is to download the newest magyar.ldf from http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/lakk/texmf/tex/generic/magyar/magyar.ldf (which fixes the warning), or use `\UseRawInputEncoding`.

Comment: An upload of the newest magyar.ldf to CTAN is in progress. It should be available soon.

Answer (score 1):

use `\usepackage[latin2,utf8]{inputenc}` and everything should be fine.